# How to install Meteor effectively

Tags: meteor

I have seen many way to install Meteor.

In the official documentation says:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

In other tutorials I have seen stuff like

```
sudo curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

I was wondering. Does it make a difference? What is the difference using "sudo"? What about if by default I usually use another shell like `zsh`?

I ask because I have usually problems installing platform and running it on android devices, like not findining $ANDROID_HOME. But that is not the point of this question. What I want to know is: Is it important the exact command I use to install Meteor? Why? And what should the proper one be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` installs meteor with admin privileges, which you should try to avoid if you can as it does not need admin privileges. `zsh` should work fine with executing the script, but it really does not make a difference if you use `sh`. All it is doing is executing the file. The recommended way to install is what is in the official documentation:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```